# Low power USB C power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, usb-c, usb-pd

I am searching for a tiny board to that accepts an usb-c cable and outputs 5v.

To my understanding, for the few hundred milliamps two 5k1 resistors on the board would suffice. PD is not needed.

I already bought [this](https://www.amazon.de/Pololu-Type-C-Connector-Breakout-Board/dp/B07GZKMPJ8/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=usb%20c%20diy%20socket&qid=1603465656&sr=8-1), but sadly it's too big. Also, I don't need any data pins, just 5v and -.

Can anyone recommend such a board to power a tiny circuit?

Comment: If that's too big, (!) you'll probably have to design your own.

Comment: If you only need the power lines, get pair of shears or a saw and make it smaller.

Comment: If you just need to accept a USB-C cable, why not simply buy a USB-C connector and solder directly to that? Honestly, this is a bit of a guess, but to me, this all sounds like "I want to design a really small product, but I don't want to design my own PCB", and I'd say that might be something you won't get around.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Depending on how much current you actually need. You can get away without using anything at all, just 5V straight to whatever you power and nothing else on datalines if you need really low current. You can always implement bc 1.2 standard with resistors. If space is critical, you can place resistors on your pcb even closer or use a micro usb port (yes, they're old, but they're a lot smaller)